# Como desabilitar o botão home do android

Tags: android

Estou precisando desabilitar o uso do botão físico do aparelho Android (de preferência das versões superiores a 4.0).
Com pesquisas encontrei algumas soluções como por exemplo removendo o actionbar, deixando a aplicação em "fullscreen". 
Necessito usar o actionbar.
Encontrei uma solução não muito boa, que usa os seguintes tags no manifest:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />                 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />               
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
```

Com isso apresenta um popup perguntando qual ação quero usar, Tela Inicial do aparelho ou chamar minha aplicação.
Ao selecionar minha aplicação, uma nova instância da aplicação é criada...

**Resumindo, preciso bloquear a ativação/ uso do botão físico home do aparelho dentro da aplicação. Não posso remover o actionbar, não posso iniciar nova instância da aplicação e, não posso bloquear o botão voltar (back button físico).**

Comment: [Essa questão](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key) do SO discute esse tema. Especificamente, a [primeira resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7964513/3569421) à questão parece funcionar. Eu ainda não testei, mas...

Comment: Mas não posso remover o actionbar, a primeira remove o action.

Comment: Oi Victor! Entendi... Nesse caso, seria interessante que você editasse a pergunta para deixar isso claro, para o pessoal não ter que vir ler os comentários.

Comment: Realizei a edição Carlos, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

O botão Home do Android por motivos de segurança foi feito para não poder ser bloqueado por aplicativos.

Qualquer forma que você encontre de fazer isso é basicamente um Hack que não existe garantias de que vá funcionar ou que vá se comportar da mesma forma em todas as versões do Android ou mesmo em aparelhos diferentes ou que usem uma UI personalizada, apenas com o SDK do Android não vai ter nada que te permita fazer isso.

A única forma de se fazer isso sem usar alguma artimanha é se o seu App for a Home Screen, a Home Screen vai ser o único app que vai poder tratar a tecla Home.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta importar esta solução https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker

Permite bloquear tanto o botao **FISICO** HOME, BACK ou MENU key em versoes 4.0+

no teu código basta usar:

```
HomeKeyLocker homeKeyLoader = new HomeKeyLocker();
homeKeyLocker.lock(this);
     // home key locked 
homeKeyLocker.unlock();
     // home key unlocked
```

Comment: Pedro, usei o projeto que você me informou. infelizmente esta muito estranho o funcionamento dele no meu sistema. Não sei se é porque uso actionbar e fragments. Ao apertar o botão home, ele apresenta a tela inicial do aparelho mas, sem os ícones. Somente volta ao normal o aparelho (apresentando os ícones) finalizando a aplicação. E, o projeto impede o uso do botão voltar físico. Preciso dele funcional. Obrigado pela ajuda apesar de infelizmente não funcionar.